# Android - Listen to changes in android contacts and get the deltas

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to understand the whole concept of sync adapters from last couple of weeks and have few questions regarding the functionality.

I want to listen to all the changes in android contacts

> Approach 1:

I have created a custom account and also created a sync adapter.
Written a broadcast listener listening to  `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` and in 
`public void onChange(boolean selfChange)` of `ContentObserver` class i'm calling `ContentResolver.requestSync(account,ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,bundle)` which is acting as a trigger point to start the sync adapter when ever there is a change to contacts data.

Everything looks fine till here but in the SyncAdapter class i'm not getting any data in `SyncResult` variable in `onPerofmSync`

> So how Can I get the delta changes from contacts?

Correct me if this is not the way to trigger sync adapter.

> Approach 2:

I have followed some example where they were talking about querying the contacts database where `dirtyFlag` is set to 1.
I was able to get the changes but my question is

> who will set that `dirtyFlag` value back to '0' ?

If I have to do that then lets say there are multiple applications on the phone which does the same thing. If some application sets the flag to '0' before my application tries to access the information. I'll be missing out on all the changes.

> Approach 3:

Query the database and keep track of `version` for each contact in my own database and if 'version' has changed consider that as a change in contact. This looks like a heavy process.

> Finally my question is what is the best way to listen to changes in
>   contacts on user's device?

Comment: i m late here but the first approach is near to the recommended way of doing it => https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter#RunDataChange

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is persist (possibly using a local `MySql` database) a mapping between [Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY) and its [RawContacts.VERSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#VERSION) values.

Once you get a broadcast that a change happened in the `Contacts` DB (via `onChange`) you query for all `RawContacts.VERSION`s and their `Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY` and compare it to the state your have persisted before, if one of them changed, you'd know that contact changed.

Comment: Yeah this is the 3rd approach as in my question.

Comment: yep, so that's what I would do, it's not such a heavy process, and I don't see any way to do this without a query that goes over all contacts.

Comment: So on every time there is the tiniest trigger of the "registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI" call, we should perform a query of the entire contacts to see what has changed vs what we have?

Comment: you can use the `CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP` from the Contacts table, to query for just to recently changed contacts, see:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP (note this field is from API 18 and above only)

Comment: @marmor Interesting, so you mean I can perform a query of just the contacts that have a higher value of the timestamp I've recently got, and this will return only contacts that were updated? Do you know perhaps of a nice sample for this?